# How can I watermark images with a taxonomy term from the node they belong to?

Tags: tokens

I'm working on a site for a business who would like to watermark all their product photos with the brand name of the product (which is a taxonomy term reference field on the product content type).

Looking into this, I found a variety of modules that will watermark images in various ways, but most expect to just put a single image or text overlay on all images of a given style, which is not what I need here.

The one exception I found was Textimage, which works with the Image Effects module and, at least in theory, supports node tokens. But when I tried out those two modules, I was unable to get any token for the taxonomy field in question to work. I tried [node:field_brand] and [node:field_brand:entity:name] without success — it just put the text of the token instead of replacing it with the brand. Other tokens, like [node:title], did work, but not the one I wanted (even though it was in the list of available tokens).

I posted to the issues queue for Textimage, but it doesn't seem like anyone's monitoring it regularly, and I'm on a deadline.

Does anyone know either how I can get the node replacement to work in Textimage, or alternatively any other way of doing this? I'm not at all wedded to Textimage and Image Effects — they're just the only modules thus far that claim to be able to do what I need to do.

Comment: Have you exposed your custom field_brand in the appropriate entity type view settings?

Comment: I just double-checked the setup of the field itself and yes, it turns out I made a mistake in setting up the field on the test content type I was using! So the problem was 100% on my end, and is now solved. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved — Rainer Feike's comment prompted me to examine the field setup and I realized I had made an error in the way I set it up that was causing the token not to resolve (there were two taxonomy fields on the original product content type, referencing two different vocabularies, and I had matched the wrong field name with the vocabulary in setting up the test content type I was trying out the new image style on).

Once I corrected that it worked. My apologies for posting about what turned out to be a self-created problem.